# AppleScript Loop Print All File Folder Names Path

Tags: applescript

Help I need to print into the output of IDE all of the folder and file names contained in a folder. Here is my code so far:

```
set Music_Collection_Folder to POSIX file "/Volumes/A_Live HD/Music/Collection" as alias
set the_string to ""
tell application "Finder"
repeat with this_item in (get items of ("/Volumes/A_Live HD/Music/Collection"))
set the_string to the_string & name of this_item & tab & modification date of this_item & tab & size of this_item & tab & kind of this_item & return
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: looks like a Homework starting file

Comment: Haha not homework, I have 15000 files and 800 folders in this path and I need to loop through all of them to format the name correctly, but this is my first applescript so Im just getting the loop down first then going for the rest of the work. Also, i am writing this inside VS Code so I want to be able to see the output inside of the output window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an alias of the target folder. **Use it!**

The Finder has no idea what a POSIX path is

```
repeat with this_item in (get items of Music_Collection_Folder) ...
```

Comment: that works! was the issue me not using the POSIX file object? Is that the only way to loop through files in a folder?